# How to use webpack to properly bundle a umd dependency

Tags: webpack, import, umd

I am using webpack to bundle a legacy es5 webapp and i need to import some dependencies in umd format, e.g.

```
import 'moment/min/moment-with-locales.min.js'
```

I want webpack simply bundles it into the final application bundle without changing anything. However, it seems that webpack is transforming the umd module into something like below during build time

```
(function(module) {
    !function(a, b) {
        true ? module.exports = b() : undefined
    }
```

Note the true above, this obviously will fail the bundle to load in browser as it treats browser as CommonJS env. Is there any settings/config I can use to preventing this instead of using https://webpack.js.org/loaders/expose-loader/ as a workaround ?

Answer (score 0):

[script-loader](https://v4.webpack.js.org/loaders/script-loader/) solved my problem. Basically i want some 3rd party libraries loaded as global variables(e.g. `window.$`f or jQuery) due to working on a legacy codebase migration.

<sup>note: webpack modules also has a [noparse](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#modulenoparse) option that prevents above transformation, but it does't solve my problem due to above code is actually loaded by webpack and thus still treated as cjs module</sup>.